# How to use button for submitting form?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an asp.net mvc form with a `button` that is used for submitting the form.  The problem is the button doesn't do anything.  I'm using the Bootstrap framework for styling.

This doesn't work:

```
<button type=button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Send It</button>
```

But if I add this, it works:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Is there a way to use the Bootstrap styled button for submitting the form?

Comment: Try changing the button type to submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change yout button type to submit:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Send It</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

A [`button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) of type `button` has no behaviour attached to it by default. To submit a form you should use the `submit` type, instead.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Send It</button>
```